# how to install pygame 1.9.4 in anaconda

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda

I am using Windows 10 with Anaconda python 3.7 The latest version of pygame I can find to install is 1.9.2 which only uses python 2.7. Does anyone know how to install pygame 1.9.4 which is compatible with python 3.7 in Anaconda? The command I have used to install pygame 1.9.2 is:

conda install -c cogsci pygame

Comment: You can use `pip install` instead. The Anaconda repository seems to be not completely updated

Comment: I tried pip. it did install it, but didn't make it available to Anaconda, Spyder etc

Answer (score 2):

The repository is not up to date with version 1.9.4.
You can try the following instead:

- Download the [1.9.4 package](https://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.4.tar.gz) from the pygame website
- Install it
  `conda install --offline [path]\pygame-1.9.4.tar.gz`

Comment: I tried this, but is there supposed to be something in the [path]? I tried putting in the path where it was stored. I also tried navigating to where the file was stored and then running the command

Comment: The path is the file location. It can be relative or absolute. If you navigate to the location folder you can leave it out.

Comment: I couldn't ever get that to work, but I did find a solution in                                   pip install Pygame==1.9.4. I found it at https://pypi.org/project/Pygame/1.9.4/. The only catch is Anaconda Navigator doesn't acknowledge that it is installed, but Spyder and Jupyter do